# Use the same user control xaml with different view models in Prism

Tags: xaml, mvvm, prism

I have an abstract base view model (IBaseViewModel) and two classes that implement it (Base1ViewModel, Base2ViewModel). I also have a Xaml user control, and I want in one page to use Base1ViewModel as view model and in another page Base2ViewModel as view model.

Prism best practice is to bind to view model by name, so what I ended up doing is duplicating the xaml file into Base1View and Base2View so each view gets the right view model, but this is obviously not ideal because then changes to the xaml should be duplicated as well.

Is there a solution/design in which I can reuse the same xaml user control with two different view models?

Thanks,
Noam

Comment: Why do you want to use two different view models? I suppose either the view could be more specific (i.e. two different views) or you could use the same view model but with a different model/data source behind it.

Comment: A little bit of both. Consider similar UI structure - buttons/lists with different data source, and in addition, when clicking buttons in Base2ViewModel the behavior is slightly different than in Base1ViewModel. So the abstract base does almost everything, while the derived classes may point to different web Urld and perhaps make some changes to the base implementation.

Comment: You can manually provide a view model for your view rather than relying on the PRISM's auto-wire mechanism. How do you instantiate/show the views?